# Having alignment issues in Nested Items with List Dividers in an ionic1 app

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a list with cities under each state code.
I have an array of states like this:

```
states = [{ state:"AK", 
            Cities:[{cityName:"Anchorage",
                   cityCode:"ANC"},
                  {cityName:"Barrow",
                   cityCode: "BRW"}]
         },

         {
           state:"AL",
           Cities:[{cityName:"Anniston",
               cityCode:"ANB"},
              {cityName:"Birhimgham",
               cityCode: "BHM"}]
     }]
```

Now, i want to display the list of cities by state where state are list headers.

```
 <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
       <ion-item class="item-divider" ng-repeat="state in states"> {{state.state}} 
         <ion-list>
           <ion-item ng-repeat="city in state.Cities">
          {{city.CityName}}
           </ion-item>
         </ion-list>
       </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
```

The above code gives output as:
But, it currently looks like[image]

I want the output to look like [image]

How to make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list ng-repeat="state in states">
        <ion-list-header>{{state.state}}</ion-list-header>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="city in state.Cities">{{city.CityName}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Or this one's exact:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item-group ng-repeat="state in states">
    <ion-item-divider color="light">{{state.state}}</ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="city in state.Cities">{{city.CityName}}</ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
</ion-content>
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list-dividers

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats what i needed.